# Query to Group By based on the Date order

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table such as:

[image]

I want to compress it with dates to get:

[image]

I was using 'GROUP BY' but it didn't work as it will combine all the 'T's. How can I enforce SQL Server to keep the order as its grouping?

Comment: Please show the query that you're having difficulty with.

Comment: Please post code and data as text, not images.

Comment: "I was using 'GROUP BY' but it didn't work".  Where's the query???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical gaps-and-island problem. You can assign row numbers to records within groups of records sharing the same `name`, and within groups sharing the same `name` *and* `type`. The difference between the row numbers give you the group each record belongs to.

Consider:

```
SELECT 
   name,
   MIN(date) FromDate,
   MAX(date) ToDate,
   type
FROM (
    SELECT 
        t.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY date) rn1,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name, type ORDER BY date) rn2
    FROM mytable t
) x
GROUP BY name, rn1 - rn2, type
ORDER BY name, FromDate
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b9145ac99193148e7f608068037a0363)**:

```
name | FromDate |   ToDate | type
:--- | -------: | -------: | :---
Jack | 19700715 | 19890831 | T   
Jack | 19910920 | 19920526 | N   
Jack | 19930409 | 20160411 | T
```